# Form Jquery Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to show div by clicking on a button form. I know its wrong just not to sure what to write, and should i write it on my javascript page or just in the view.

```
<%= submit_tag "Next Step", :type => 'button', :onclick => '$('#devregothinf').hide();' %>

<div id="devregothinf">
  <h2>General Information</h2>
  <%= render 'geninfor_step', form: f %>
</div>
```

i am getting an error as follow

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
```

Comment: If you wanted to show the div, then why have you written hide first?

Comment: its actually show on this part, i am trying to toggle, i just cant get onclick div.show

Comment: What is your requirement, can you make me clear?

Comment: its a multi step form wizard, i just want to click on the next button to show the next part of the form

Comment: Write what I am posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as following:

```
<span onclick = "$('#devregothinf').slideToggle('slow');"> Next Step </span>

<div id="devregothinf" style="display:none;">
 <h2>General Information</h2>
 <%= render 'geninfor_step', form: f %>
</div>
```

Comment: Otherwise you can write `$('#devregothinf').show('slow');` also

Comment: so instead of using a submit form i should use a span?

Comment: Yes, better writing something else rather traditional submit tag

Comment: It works, but i don't see a mouse over it, would css fix it? span:hover of some sort?

Comment: You can put your styles according your wish. Eg:<span style="cursor:pointer; color:#AF12ED;" onclick = "$('#devregothinf').slideToggle('slow');"> Next Step </span>

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get it to show and not hide, you just need to change $('#devregothinf').hide(); to $('#devregothinf').show();

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

**view (app/views/home.html.erb)**

```
<%= link_to 'Next Step', 'home/next_step', :remote => true %>

<div id="devregothinf">
```

**controller (app/controllers/home_controller.rb)**

```
def next_step
  <your code>
  respond_to do |format|
      format.js
  end
end
```

***view (js.erb) (app/views/next_step.html.erb)***

```
$("#devregothinf").html("<%= raw escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'form')) %>")
```

***view (app/views/_form.html.erb)***

```
Your form partial
```

HTH